# Fastest way to generate dictionary from two lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists. For example:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1]
```

and

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I want to create a dictionary of lists out of them as shown below:

```
dict = {1: [1, 7], 2: [2, 4, 6], 3: [3], 4: [5]}
```

What is the fastest way to do it and what generates the efficiency gains, both by using any module and also by not importing any additional module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(keys, values):
    d_dict[k].append(v)

dict(d_dict)
#{1: [1, 7], 2: [2, 4, 6], 3: [3], 4: [5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
d = {}
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print(d)
```

which outputs:

```
{1: [1, 7], 2: [2, 4, 6], 3: [3], 4: [5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`defaultdict`](https://kite.com/python/docs/collections.defaultdict) for your case. In case if some key does not exist the default dict calls the factory method (`list()` for current case) and instead of raising KeyError it will return new empty list, that is appended with value:

```
from collections import defaultdict

ld = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in zip(keys, values):
    ld[k].append(v)

print(ld)
```